# JavaScript visual timeline graph for time intervals

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, vis.js

I have been using `vis.js` for the last few days trying to achieve what I need with no success.

I got a list of online users like that:
`[{x: 09:00, y: 0}, {x: 09:10, y: 1}, {x: 09:20, y: 2}]`
in such case I want to draw a graph that will have 3 rectangles, the first will be `00:10 x 0` and wont be visible, then `00:10 x 1` and last `00:10 x 2` so the end result would be something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XXDI.png)

I tried to do thing with visjs but I am only able to draw a graph (like the function is continuous)

Then I tried doing this with bars: but the bars width is fixed (I cant set different bar's width for each bar)

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var items = [
    {x: '09:00', y: 0},
    {x: '09:10', y: 1},
    {x: '09:20', y: 2}
  ];

  var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
  var options = {
    start: '09:00',
    end: '09:20'
  };
  var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, dataset, options);
</script>
```

Comment: Please share your code in order to help you properly.

Comment: Sorry. added...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
function DateFromHours(date, hourString) {
  var split = hourString.split(":");
  date.setHours(split[0]);
  date.setMinutes(split[1]);
  return date
}

var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var items = [
  {x: "09:00", y: 0}, 
  {x: "09:10", y: 1}, 
  {x: "09:20", y: 2}
];

items.forEach(function (item) {
  item.x = DateFromHours(new Date(), item.x);
});

var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
var options = {
    style:'bar',
    barChart: {width:50, align:'center'}, // align: left, center, right
    drawPoints: false,
    dataAxis: {
        icons:true
    },
    orientation:'top',
    start: DateFromHours(new Date(), '9:00'),
    end: DateFromHours(new Date(), '10:00')
};
var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, items, options);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

I derived it from [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/graph2d/02_bars.html). You can right click on the page and do the inspect command on it to find the javascript for it.

I looked at the api docs [here](http://visjs.org/docs/graph2d/#items) and it appears that your x has to be a valid date so I updated all your values to be valid date formats (strings that can be parsed to dates should work to, but '9:00' isn't specific enough for the date parser).

I used [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to update your x properties of your objects in your array. I also used some standard properties of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object that's given in JavaScript

Comment: As you can see - it doesnt work as I want it. If you zoom in there is a white space between the bars.

Comment: @Daniel sorry I must have read your question incorrectly I may take a look at it tomorrow but it is 1:00 am here so I'm going to bed first. Hopefully someone will answer your question before I get back to it so you won't have to wait very long. Yet again sorry for not really helping yet.